# How to send downtime message from services to use it in mobile app

Tags: java, android, rest, mobile

I am developing services/api's which are being used in mobile application. Mobile app calling those services and binding the data.

I want to write services in a way so that if donwtime/maintenance is going on mobile app should bind to a particular screen.

How can I develop this structure across the services, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create an API which can provide details like if service is up or not.

On launch of your mobile app, in loading screen or splash screen, you can check if your service is up or not!

Based on the the response, you can show respective screen on mobile.

If your new service also not responding, you can set timeout on mobile app to show generic error!

Comment: This will not be accurate enough. If I am using mobile app for 5 mins after launch, app will not come do know.

Comment: If you are sure that your APIs will respond within few seconds, then the best option would be setting Timeout on your mobile application, and then show Downtime screen.

Comment: Setting timeout will not be accurate as there could be various reasons for not returning data.